# Which capacitor for a high current resonant system?

Tags: capacitor, power-electronics

I would like to build a induction heater.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fui404.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

V1 will be a ZVS system that is out of scope of the question.
Accordint to my computations and confirmed with simulations, the current into C1 will be a sine of 56A RMS at a frequency of 100kHz. 70V pk-pk.

I may consider replacing C1 by several capacitor to reduce the current rating of each of them. I may also consider adding a radiator if needed.

In summary the requirements are (at 100kHz):

- 56A rms
- 70V pk-pk
- Not polarized
- 2.2uF or less if several in //.

What capacitor technologies are suited to this application?

Comment: Why are you using a 2.2uF capacitor? I'd expect \$f_{RES}=\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{LC}}\$ to be around 100kHz, instead it's about 76kHz. Just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for starters, at 100 kHz, a 2u2 cap will have an impedance of 0.723 ohms. With 70V p-p applied (sinewave) the RMS voltage is 25 V and therefore the current is 34A RMS.

You should be looking for capacitors that are COG/NP0 - these have the lowest losses and maybe you can get away with X7R dielectrics. You might also consider increasing your coil inductance by a good margin so that the capacitor values are reduced and fewer parallel caps are needed.

I don't know how you are winding your coil but I'm guessing you are using Litz wire to avoid high resistance losses in the coil.

As a side note - I've used a bank of 100nF ceramic COG/NP0 capacitors to run at 12A RMS in parallel with a single large coil for a metal detection product. The tuning was very important - it had to stay stable and these sorts of caps are the best.

Comment: Could you not make it auto tune or self resonant?

Comment: @joe it was self resonating but the phase stability needed to be so very, very good.

Comment: Ah , and high Q loaded = low Q and noisy phase off centre, plus dynamic permittivity changes, makes it almost as tough as tuning Jaguars with six SU carbs

Comment: @joe it was looking for minute metal pieces on a food line. To avoid effects from the actual food product both I and Q were demodulator from the received signal and the food had a definite signature of I to Q ratio so this was used to null out product effects which were prob abt ten times bigger than the contaminate signal.

Comment: Cool. I've used I,Q on 100KHz & 200kHz with 100 ppm vector impedance resolution for eddy current tester, which detect pin holes or 10% thickness variation in steel tubing

Answer (score 1):

The best type are plastic dielectric (self healing) conduction cooled, low DF , high Freq

Polypropylene or Polyester only.   Anything else might explode after wearout from thermal runaway.

These class of caps are rated in reactive power. Your requirements may not match common parts.  But you are looking at 6 kVAR at. 100V

Here is a great source for bigger ones, ask who has smaller ones. http://www.celem.com/index.aspx?id=2758

Otherwise EPCOS, Panasonic , Vishay

In all you will need X and Y1 class for EMI filters and Low ESR high SRF for 100KHz.

Although at this power level and frequency, it would work on Aluminum Pots BUT also work on not pure gold jewelry.   http://www.epcos.com/action/epcos-en/373562/tech-library/articles/applications---cases/applications---cases/171866/pdf.do